# Impossible to update state while typing in input in fresh

Tags: javascript, server-side, deno, preact, freshjs

I am new using Fresh by Deno, and I am trying to update the state of a Preact component while typing text into an input.

```js
export default function Calculous(props: CalculousProps) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');

  const onSubmit = (event: h.JSX.TargetedEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(input);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(input);
  }, [input])

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
        <button disabled={isNaN(Number(input))} type="submit">Next</button>
      </form>
  );
}
```

However, when I type text on my component, it doesn't re-render until I unfocus the input. Do you know how to trigger re-rendering to update my state ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally [use `onInput` instead of `onChange`](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/differences-to-react#use-oninput-instead-of-onchange) when using Preact with an input element.

React chose to use the name `onChange` for the event listener callback property for both the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) events. Preact's API is more semantic and better aligned with the spec in this case.

Comment: Using ```onInput``` functions well, thanks a lot